Completely disabling mouse in ncurses
I am wondering how to completely disable mouse functionality in ncurses. I do not want to use the gpm lib.
Is the switch HAVE_LIBGPM in ncurses_def.h the way to go?
Thank you
Vaclav

That's done with mousemask:

To make mouse events visible, use the mousemask  function.   This  sets
the  mouse  events  to  be  reported.   By default, no mouse events are
reported.

The module which supports this is not optional, but one can configure a terminal description which prevents it from using the xterm mouse protocol.  See the source:
#if !defined(USE_TERM_DRIVER) || defined(EXP_WIN32_DRIVER)
    /* we know how to recognize mouse events under "xterm" */
    if (NonEmpty(key_mouse)) {
        init_xterm_mouse(sp);
    } else if (strstr(SP_TERMTYPE term_names, "xterm") != 0) {
        if (_nc_add_to_try(&(sp->_keytry), xterm_kmous, KEY_MOUSE) == OK)
            init_xterm_mouse(sp);
    }
#endif


And is it possible to completely disable the mouse module (so it won't compile and link)?

gpm is only part of the mouse module - but the linkage to gpm can be disabled.
